# Make Webpack aliases not apply in node_modules

Tags: javascript, webpack

I made an alias in webpack.config.js, but I want that alias to apply only in my app code, not in node_modules.

Here's the alias:

```
alias: {
  'jss': path.resolve('path', 'to', 'custom', 'jss')
}
```

I would like something similar to `rules` (or `loaders` in Webpack v1) where we can write

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```

so that the rules/loaders don't apply to node_modules.

How can we do this with aliases?

For example, there's a package inside `node_modules` that does `require('jss')`, and I want it to get the actual `jss` package, not my customized module.